# Assign Form1_Closing method to Form Closing Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following method defined to be called when a form closes

`private void TimeKeeper_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)`

However, it doesn't show up in the list when I try to assign it in the Events section of the Form properties. Is there something I need to do to get it to show up there?

EDIT: Sorry, originally posted the wrong method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Closing event is obsolete, it dates from .NET 1.x.  Microsoft goofed that one pretty badly and it was replaced in .NET 2.0 with the FormClosing event.  Which tells you a lot more about *why* the form is getting closed.  The e.CloseReason is very important, you don't want to prevent Windows from shutting down.

Which is why you can't find it, you are not supposed to use it anymore.  Note how the answer you accepted just stops your program from compiling.  You probably discovered the FormClosing event by yourself.

Might as well go whole-hog and point out how silly it is for a class to listen to its own events.  Events are meant for *other* code.  They work pretty well in the designer, that's why you end up writing code like this.  But the sane thing to do is to just override the method:

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
            // Some code that might set e.Cancel = true
            //...
        }
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
```

Which has many advantages, beyond the typical lossage of forgetting to subscribe the event with the designer, a derived class can simple alter the decision being made here by setting e.Cancel back to true.

Comment: I didn't even catch that in the answer I accepted. I had been using FormClosing anyway, and I just had to change the parameter in order to be able to find it. Thanks for your answer though, I appreciate the thorough response.

Comment: Actually, I notice you went with "OnFormClosing" instead of "Form1_Closing". What is the difference?

Comment: That's the "whole-hog" section of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change EventArgs to FormClosingEventArgs

```
private void TimeKeeper_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Note: Your answer is correct, but I'm using the FormClosing event, not just Closing.

Comment: I am also using FormClosing event, there is no Closing event. Thanks to Hans Passant I also know why.